# I need to create an array with numbers given by the user, it works but keeps giving me 0

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

```
System.out.println("Please enter a coefficients of a polynomial’s terms:");
    String coefficents = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] three = coefficents.split(" ");
    int[] intArray1 = new int[three.length];

for (int i = 0; i < intArray1.length; i++) {
 System.out.print(intArray1[i]);
}
```

//Does anyone know how i can make this work because right not it builds but when i run it, it gives me 0

//if someone could show me or explain to me what's wrong that would help

Comment: You created the array and then never put anything in it.

Comment: Add this as the first line of the loop: `intArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(three[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you created the array `intArray1` and you printed it without adding any elements to it. That's why it gives `0` as the result.
Instead of creating `intArray1`, print out the array `three` in the following way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the coefficients of a polynomial’s terms:");
        String coefficents = user_input.nextLine();
        String[] three = coefficents.split(" ");
        for (String i: three) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```